# after linking a data stream to big query how to get all historical data

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have data from the stream on GA for the last 3 days but I just connected it to the big query links. I see the current day's data but I question how do I get the last 3 days of data over as well.

I have checked the events_* and specific days but I do not see them loaded.

Comment: Are you asking how to backfill your BigQuery data with GA4 data created before you linked two accounts?

Comment: Yes, I am missing the data before the link was created. I see the data in GA4 but Big query is only getting any new data